# I tried from POSTMAN API working fine but not from my Rest assured code

Tags: rest, automation, rest-assured

Getting response as "Response: tcp_error: A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
"

From POSTMAN/Curl

```
    curl -X POST \
  http://IP:PORT/{endpoint} \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 5' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: IP:PORT' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 053670e6-44d4-4d03-96bf-ab1178b02d06,ffad205d-320a-4cd0-a63d-1687873fbf1d' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0' \
  -H 'appkey: ACTUAL APP KEY' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{

}'
```

**Rest Assured code for the above API**

```
RestAssured.baseURI = “http://IP”;
        RestAssured.port = port;
        RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();

        Response response = RestAssured.given()

                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("appkey", “ACTUAL APPKEY”)
                .when()
                .get(“ENDPOINT”);

        System.out.println("Response: " + response.asString());
```

Comment: Post the code, what have you tried, show us the request from Postman.

Comment: Fenio, updated with code and postman request details as curl

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the encoder config in rest assured. It will solve the issue.

```
given().config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(encoderconfig.appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)));
```